# Android | can create a dot color ball in a list?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, user-interface

guys i want to create a list for showing colors of product and i see some ui and now i dont have any idea how can i implement this ui!
i want read colors in database then apply them to a list like below and user choose what color want...i search many site and video and stack question and i cant find correct answer for this...
can anyone help me to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cardview` and its property `cornerRadius` to achieve this round shape. Now for the different color you can set the `backgroundTint` of cardview with your desired color to get the expected result.